# What does modified date of application means?

Tags: macos, mac, imac, google-chrome

Today I updated the chrome app on my Mac but when I checked in the application section of Finder I see the modified date as 30th April? Why is that? On the get info page the version shown matches with the version I updated to and this version was released just 2 days ago. Also the created date is different from the date I downloaded and installed chrome on this device on 12th March and it is the visible when the check the information of the googlechrome.dmg filee but on the chrome app the created date is showing as 22 Feb. I am using IMac and device is purchased from apple.com. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing is the date that the app was created or modified - by the developer!

The exact behaviour will vary depending on how the app was downloaded and installed, but this is the correct behaviour.

To explore it a bit:

- Open the Applications folder in Finder;
- Change the View to List;
- Right click (or Control-Click) on the heading row (e.g. where it says
  Name) and add additional columns - in this case Date Added, Created
  and Modified;
- Sort by Date Added (if you wish).

Now you will see that the Date Added really is the date and time you installed the app.

Date Created is usually earlier than Date Added - exceptions include applications that are part of macOS (e.g. Calendar) where all three dates are the same.

Something that confuses people is that Date Added is a property of the folder, whilst Date Created and Date Modified are properties of the file (or app). Hence: 1) Date Added does not appear in the Get Info window, and 2) when you move or copy a file to a new folder, the Date Added changes in the new folder, but not the Dates Created or Modified.